# Dask: Where do SSHCluster workers log to? (KilledWorker exception)

Tags: logging, dask, dask-distributed

I wrote a little starter script for dask `SSHCluster` and `LocalCluster` which works great (see below).

But when I let it run and a worker crashes with the

`KilledWorker: ("('from-delayed-pandas_read_text-read-block-head-1-1-from-delayed-f0f78ffea007aeeccc7a9e04880d0195', 0)", <Worker 'tcp://192.168.56.11:34965', name: 0, memory: 0, processing: 1>)`

exception, I wonder where I can find the **crash logs** / **tracebacks** of the remote workers? Is there a way to collect them centerally on the Scheduler Host? Or are there some logs on the remote machines?

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691675/what-do-killedworker-exceptions-mean-in-dask) only states, that it is logging to `stdout` - But I can not find any logs there as well..

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, SSHCluster
import time, datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, sys
from collections import Counter

# Add Home Folder of CGi to path
os.environ["HOME"] = "/home/cgi/"
os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
#os.path.expanduser('/home/cgi/')
#os.path.expandvars('/home/cgi/')


def run_cluster(local=0, HOST = '10.8.0.1', SCHEDULER_PORT = 8711, DASHBOARD_PORT=8710,
                DASK_WORKER_PROCESSES = 16, NTHREADS=2, SILENCE_LOGS = 0):

    start_msg = "Starting a "
    if local: start_msg += "local"
    else: start_msg += "ssh"
    start_msg += " dask cluster. SCHEDULER_PORT=%s and DASHBOARD_PORT=%s." % ( SCHEDULER_PORT, DASHBOARD_PORT )
    print(start_msg)

    dashboard_address = ':%s' % DASHBOARD_PORT

    if local:
        cluster = LocalCluster(dashboard_address=dashboard_address, scheduler_port=SCHEDULER_PORT,
                               n_workers=DASK_WORKER_PROCESSES, host=HOST, silence_logs=SILENCE_LOGS)
    else:
        worker_hosts = [
            "localhost", "localhost", "localhost", "localhost",
            "192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11",
            "192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11",
            "192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11",
            "192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11",
            "192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11","192.168.56.11"
        ]
        print("Starting a DASK SSHCluster with (%s) workers on %s different hosts... "
              % len(worker_hosts), len(set(worker_hosts)))

        cluster = SSHCluster(
            worker_hosts,
            connect_options = {"known_hosts": None},
            worker_options = {"nthreads": NTHREADS},
            scheduler_options={"port": SCHEDULER_PORT, "dashboard_address": dashboard_address}
        )
        print("SSHCLUSTER>%s" % cluster)

    print("DASK Cluster Dashboard = http://%s%s/status" % (HOST, dashboard_address))

    #cluster.scale(3)
    client = Client(cluster)
    #print(cluster)
    print(client)
    print("Press Enter to quit ...")
    while (not time.sleep(5)):
        continue
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Webserver which runs the dash/plotly dashboard(s). Name: BT_HISTORY')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--local-cluster', help='1/0', required=False, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', help='1/0', required=False, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-dp', '--dashboard-port', help='port to run dashboard (default=%s)' % 8710, default=8710, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-sp', '--scheduler-port', help='port to run scheduler (default=%s)' % 8711, default=8711, required=False)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    print("args>%s" % args)
    LOCAL = int(args['local_cluster'])
    DASHBOARD_PORT = int(args['dashboard_port'])
    SCHEDULER_PORT = int(args['scheduler_port'])
    SILENCE_LOGS = int(args['quiet'])

    run_cluster(local=LOCAL, DASHBOARD_PORT=DASHBOARD_PORT, SCHEDULER_PORT=SCHEDULER_PORT, SILENCE_LOGS=SILENCE_LOGS)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to only contain the parts relevant and essential to your question.

Comment: @mdurant The question is above the code. The code only shows how to setup an `SSHCluster`.

Answer (score 1):

A zombie message perhaps but hopefully this information will help future readers. A tip about building the "other system that handles the stdout" as referenced by the answer above.

I found it useful to build a Logging object that tries to write to the worker logs locally and reverts to the primary logging system if that doesn't work i.e. because the logging statement doesn't occur on a worker. In this pattern I wrote each worker log to a file, and the main process with the client had it's own log.

```
   try:
        return dask.distributed.get_worker().plugins[WorkerLocalLoggerPlugin.name].local_logger
    except ValueError:
        # Not on Worker
        return self.standard_logger
```

As you see there. I wrote a WorkerPlugin that builds a local logger on the start up of a worker. In my code I try to access it via the plugins dictionary that's a part of the worker. I found this to be a less risky way of making the logs available on the workers without writing new attribute on the worker itself.

Not that you also need to divert Dask's own logs, which I did by overwriting the logging handler inside the worker plugin (this is copied from a similar post). It's probably worth setting the level to INFO from the Dask Logs. Debug is verbose.

```
   log = logging.getLogger("distributed.worker")
    for hdlr in log.handlers[:]:  # remove all old handlers
        log.removeHandler(hdlr)

    # Replace with the handler from the local_logger so the output looks the same
    log.addHandler(self.local_logger.handlers[0])
```

Hope that's helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that Dask Workers pipe data to stdout.  Collecting those logs are typically the job of some other system.

I believe that as of today (2020-06-12) the `dask-ssh` command line tool actually uses a slightly different code path that may collect logs.  You could try that.

the SSHCluster may also have a `logs` or `get_logs` method, but I suspect that it only applies to workers that are still running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I was searching through `logs` and `get_logs` already and could not find the killed works. I need to do some parameter checking on `dask-ssh` and will give it a try again when my working `LocalCluster` is getting too much on my nervous with waiting time.

Comment: @MRocklin would `dask_client.forward_logging()` do this job today?