# Worker killed during running Dask on reading file SFTP

Tags: python, async-await, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am trying to read a csv from a remote server using SFTP in Dask. Below is my code snippet

```
import time
from dask.distributed import Client, Future
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import dask
password = 'Password_123'
dask_master = '192.0.0.1:8786'
# import distributed
# distributed.config['distributed']['scheduler']['allowed-failures'] = 50
dask.config.set({'distributed.scheduler.allowed-failures': 999}) 
print(dask.config.get("distributed.scheduler.allowed-failures"))
async def call_data_load():
    data_path = r'sftp://root:'+password+'@192.0.0.2:22/root/sample_data/sample.csv'
    df =  await data_load(data_path)
    print(df.head())
    return df

async def data_load(data_path):
    async with Client(dask_master, asynchronous=True) as client:
        df = dd.read_csv(data_path,blocksize=2)
        df = await client.compute(df,npartitions=10,chunksize="8 MiB")
        print(type(df))
        return df 
    

try:
    y = asyncio.run(call_data_load())
except Exception as ex:
    raise
```

I am getting `distributed.scheduler.KilledWorker`

I tried to change the allowed failure count to 999 but still, the error persists. I am able to run it without submitting the job to the Dask cluster. the error occurs only when I am trying to submit the job to the Dask cluster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do KilledWorker exceptions mean in Dask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691675/what-do-killedworker-exceptions-mean-in-dask)

Comment: I am able to read SQL using dask but while reading from SFTP only I am getting error

Comment: `blocksize=2` seems very odd. Do you know for sure that you can do this from the worker machines?

Comment: After removing `blocksize` also I'm getting same error only